# How to selecting multiple rows and take mean value based on name of the row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

From this data frame I like to select rows with same concentration and also almost same name. For example, first three rows has same concentration and also same name except at the end of the name Dig_I, Dig_II, Dig_III. This 3 rows same with same concentration. I like to somehow select this three rows and take mean value of each column. After that I want to create a new data frame.

here is the whole data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://gist.github.com/akash062/75dea3e23a002c98c77a0b7ad3fbd25b.js")
```

[image]

Comment: `df.groupby('concentration')...`?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://gist.github.com/akash062/75dea3e23a002c98c77a0b7ad3fbd25b.js")
new_df = df.groupby('concentration').mean()
```

Note: This will only find the averages for columns with dtype float or int... this will drop the img_name column and will take the averages of all columns...
This may be faster...

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://gist.github.com/akash062/75dea3e23a002c98c77a0b7ad3fbd25b.js").groupby('concentration').mean()
```

If you would like to preserve the img_name...

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://gist.github.com/akash062/75dea3e23a002c98c77a0b7ad3fbd25b.js")
new = df.groupby('concentration').mean()
pd.merge(df, new, left_on = 'concentration', right_on = 'concentration', how = 'inner')
```

Does that help?

Comment: thanks for your answer. Your answer almost solve my problem. But there is some issue, if you use this code:  df[df['concentration']==0] you will select all the rows which have 0 concentration. But I can't take mean all 6 rows, there will be 6 rows. I want to take mean those rows which has almost same name, like: DS_P_Dig_. After grouping them based on concentration how can select rows with same name and take mean?

Comment: Are you looking to take the mean for each 'Dig_1', 'Dig_2', and 'Dig_3'? There would then be three rows for your output...

Comment: Thanks @Gess123 for your answer. Not really. I want to take mean of rows which has almost similar name. For example: 0-I DS_P_Dig_I ROI_1, 0-II DS_P_Dig_II ROI_1, 0-III DS_P_Dig_III ROI_1, this three name almost same that means data from this image are same. So I want to take mean of this three row. if you use this command df[df['concentration']==100] , you will find there is some image name almost same.